# restaurant bill, initializing error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RestaurantBill3
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      //Constant
      final double TAX_RATE = 0.0675;      
      final double TIP_PERCENT = 0.15;

      //Variables                             
      double cost;  
      double taxAmount = TAX_RATE * cost;              //Tax amount 
      double totalWTax = taxAmount + cost;             //Total with tax
      double tipAmount = TIP_PERCENT * totalWTax;            //Tip amount
      double totalCost = taxAmount + tipAmount + totalWTax;  //Total cost of meal

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("What is the cost of your meal? ");
      cost = keyboard.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Your meal cost $" +cost);

      System.out.println("Your Tax is $" + taxAmount);

      System.out.println("Your Tip is $" + tipAmount);

      System.out.println("The total cost of your meal is $" + totalCost);

      System.exit(0);                                        //End program
   }
}
```

/*
I keep receiving the error that cost has evidently not been initialized, but if it's waiting on input, how is it supposed to do that?*/

Comment: You're using `cost` in calculations before assigning it any values. Assign it a value first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at how you declare the variable `cost`. You are declaring a variable but you are not assigning it a value, hence it being uninitialized. I think there is a bigger conceptual problem though. Let's look at your code:

```
double cost;  // this is uninitialized because it has not been assigned a value yet
double taxAmount = TAX_RATE * cost;              //Tax amount 
double totalWTax = taxAmount + cost;             //Total with tax
double tipAmount = TIP_PERCENT * totalWTax;            //Tip amount
double totalCost = taxAmount + tipAmount + totalWTax;  //Total cost of meal
```

Here, what is happening is you are declaring variables and setting their value to be the result of the expression - the right hand side of the equals sign. The program flow is top down, in this case, and these statements are executed sequentially. When `taxAmount` and your other variables are declared and assigned, the value of cost is unknown. This results in a compiler error. Try rewriting your code like this, keeping in mind that `cost` needs be assigned a value before using it.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    //Constant
    final double TAX_RATE = 0.0675;      
    final double TIP_PERCENT = 0.15;

    //Variables                             
    double cost, taxAmount;  // rest of variables

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("What is the cost of your meal? ");
    cost = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Your meal cost $" +cost);

    taxAmount = TAX_RATE * cost;
    System.out.println("Your Tax is $" + taxAmount);

    // rest of code

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. not used to being "inside" of a program...makes sense that things run in the order they're written in. lol

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the value of `cost` before it's initialized here:

```
double taxAmount = TAX_RATE * cost; 
double totalWTax = taxAmount + cost;
```

Move the initialization of those variables after the initialization of `cost`, so `cost` will have a value when it's referenced.